# Why there is no ordered hashmap in Redis?

Tags: redis, in-memory-database, key-value-store, ordered-map

[Redis Data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) includes [sorted set](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#sorted-sets) and other necessary data-structures for key-value storage. But I wonder why it doesn't have any sorted map like Java's `TreeMap` or C++'s `std::map`. I think the underlying data-structure would be mostly similar of sorted set as both are supposed to be balanced binary search tree.

There must be some use-cases where we have to store key-value pair in specific order according to key. But current sorted set only serves the purpose of storing key according to score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There must be some use-cases where we have to store key-value pair in specific order according to key

Since Redis keys are binary strings, I assume that the specific order you mentioned, is lexicographical order (specifically, keys are compared with the `memcmp` function). In that case, you can easily implement a C++'s `std::map` with `SORTED SET`. You can achieve this with 2 steps:

> Build a std::set with Redis' Sorted Set

If 2 elements in a `SORTED SET` have the same score, they're ordered in lexicographical order. So in order to build a `std::set`, just give all members in a `SORTED SET` with the same score:

```
zadd std::set 0 c
zadd std::set 0 a
zadd std::set 0 b

// since all these members have the same score,
// the result is lexicographical ordered:
// a b c
zrange std::set 0 -1

// the following command will fail, since 'c' already exists.
zadd std::set 0 c
```

Since Redis 2.8, [it supports some commands](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#lexicographical-scores) to operate on the  lexicographical ranges, so that you can build something similar to  `std::set::lower_bound`, or `std::set::upper_bound`

```
// something similar to lower_bound: find all members not less than b
zrangebylex std::set [b +
// something similar to upper_bound: find all members greater than b
zrangebylex std::set (b +
```

> Map each key in the set with a value

Since you already get a `std::set`, then map the key with a value, you can get a `std::map`.

```
set a value_a
set b value_b
set c value_c
```

> Combine these 2 steps together

You can wrap the whole work into a lua script to have a *built-in* `std::map`. And use it like this:

```
redis-cli --eval map.lua map_name , key value
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I think for `zadd a value_a`,  here `a` is key and `value_a` is value in redis perspectives. But actually `a` is the name of sorted set and `value_a` is its element. If it would be like `std::map` the syntax would be `zadd std::map key value`.

Comment: There's no such data structure in Redis, so you need 2 steps to implement one, as I mentioned in the answer. If you wrap these steps in a lua script,  you can get a *built-in* `std::map`: `redis-cli --eval map.lua std::map , key value`.