# Redis: Sorted Set sorted by member ¿?

Tags: redis

The Redis [ZSET](https://redis.io/commands/zadd#sorted-sets-101) Sorted Set (member, score) sorts the set by the score.

The Redis SET are an unordered collection of unique Strings.

What I need is a method that returns the members in a Sorted Set matching a pattern as in [ZRANGEBYLEX](https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex) but with members with different scores.

Is is possible at all with redis?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking for a way to return a range of sorted set solely by lexicographic ordering?

Comment: What's you need is a [std::map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) in C++. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070174/why-there-is-no-ordered-hashmap-in-redis/40070832#40070832) is a solution to build a `std::map` with Redis.

Comment: @for_stack thanks for commenting. Does the solution you included requires storing the scores separately?, which makes it difficult to delete them as compared to them being in structure, am I correct?

Comment: @Juancki YES, you need to store scores separately. Since there's no built-in structure to support `std::map`, you have to use two built-in data structures to simulate it. When you want to delete an item, just remove it from these 2 data structures.

Comment: great, thanks for pointing in the right direction! If you post an answer I'll mark you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems I did not know about the SCAN suite. In this case [ZSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/zscan) solves this issue, however with cost O(N) where N is the number of items in sorted set because it iterates over the whole set.

Example of elements in:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> zrange l 0 -1 WITHSCORES
 1) "foodgood:irene"
 2) "1"
 3) "foodgood:pep"
 4) "1"
 5) "sleep:irene"
 6) "1"
 7) "sleep:juan"
 8) "1"
 9) "sleep:pep"
10) "1"
11) "sleep:toni"
12) "1"
13) "foodgood:juan"
14) "2"
```

Now ZSCAN for those with prefix `foodgood:`

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZSCAN l 0 match foodgood:*
1) "0"
2) 1) "foodgood:irene"
   2) "1"
   3) "foodgood:pep"
   4) "1"
   5) "foodgood:juan"
   6) "2"
```

**The first returned value "0" if zero indicates collection was completely explored.**

What I would have liked is that to be O(log(N)+M) where M is the number of elements retrieved similar to Binary Search Tree.

Comment: The result returned by ZSCAN are NOT ordered.

Comment: True, I was more worried about being able to match pattern in the members of a sorted set.